# Subject + caution; advise +object + recognize; acknowledge

Tags: grammar, phrases, syntactic-analysis, phrasal-verbs

I am in limbo about the syntax of a certain sentence I am formulating. To me, the following sentence (with the alternative word choice combinations) is intelligible and grammatical; however, when I did a corpus search, to my surprise, only a handful of search results came out, which made me a bit doubtful. Can you guys tell me how it reads to you?

> They cautioned (advised) researchers to acknowledge (recognize) that...

At first, I thought the reason for the low search result was because the verb *caution* is usually followed by a negative action (not to). But then, why there also came low search results for the verb *advise*?

Thank you!

Comment: Preliminary question: what makes you think that "caution" is an auxiliary verb?

Comment: No, it is not an auxiliary verb.

Comment: Why do you place value on a corpus search for a whole phrase? The only result Google finds for "_Can you guys tell me how it reads to you_" is this question, but that doesn't make the sentence wrong! Having said that, I would say that _advised_ sounds more natural, probably because – as you say – _cautioned against_ is the more common usage for _cautioned_..

Comment: If you want a worthwhile answer to your question, you need to provide the full sentence and not just the fragment that immediately interests you.  You also need to provide a wider context.  For example, the reason for the word 'caution' might, for all we can tell from your fragment, be about (let us say) a research procedure into something potentially dangerous, or complex enough to give rise to many possible misundunderstandings.